# How do you install an APK file in the Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, installation, apk

I finally managed to obfuscate my Android application, now I want to test it by installing the [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) file and running it on the emulator.

How can I install an APK file on the Android Emulator?

Answer (score 1174, accepted):

**You can simply drag and drop the `.apk` file of your application to the emulator and it will automatically start installing.**

Another option:

---

**Windows:**

1. Execute the emulator [(SDK Manager.exe → Tools → Manage AVDs... → New then Start)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVysAukOpCA).
2. Start the console (Windows XP), Run → type **cmd**, and move to the **platform-tools** folder of **SDK** directory.
3. Paste the *APK* file in the `android-sdk\tools` or `platform-tools` folder.
4. Then type the following command.

   ```
   adb install [.apk path]
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   adb install C:\Users\Name\MyProject\build\Jorgesys.apk
   ```

**Linux:**

1. Copy the apk file to `platform-tools` in the `android-sdk linux` folder.
2. Open **Terminal** and **navigate to `platform-tools`** folder in `android-sdk`.
3. Then execute this command:

   ```
   ./adb install FileName.apk
   ```
4. If the operation is successful (the result is displayed on the screen), then you will find your file in the launcher of your emulator.

**Mac:**

```
PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

Example:

```
PATH=$PATH:/users/jorgesys/eclipse/android-sdk-mac_64/tools
```

Then run adb.

Comment: The adb has moved to 'platform-tools' in Windows too

Comment: Just wanted to add a little something that is missing from the above answer. You must put the apk file in the "android-sdk\tools" directory. With this information, the answer works perfectly.

Comment: The answer works perfectly with @CamilleSévigny comment. You should first put the apk file in the tools directory, then set the path in cmd with the same as that of tools direcory and at last execute the apk.

Comment: Seems that the location of the APK can be freely chosen, as long as it is referenced correctly in the `adb install` command (verified on a Mac). As for the location of `adb`: on a Mac, as of at least ADT bundle version 20130522, the platform tools can be found in `$HOME/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-<date>/sdk/platform-tools`.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D, install the drivers for your device. http://www.dominantwire.com/2012/11/how-to-solve-adb-device-not-found-error.html

Comment: Wasn't that - `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server` - I had started the emulator from eclipse

Comment: The Linux link is broken.

Comment: You should not put the .apk in the platform-tools directory. Your project doesn't belong there. Use the full path on 'adb install' instead, e.g. 'adb install "C:\Users\Name\MyProject\build\myapp.apk".

Comment: this is  just an example but you´re right, will be more correct  specifing the path to the .apk file. thank you!

Comment: Step to install APK in Emulator

Comment: Step to install APK in Emulator : Step 1 -> Run the emulator step 2-> Paste the apk in SDK manager tools and platform-tools folders. Step 3->Run this command adb install AppNaem.APK .Wait for 2 min it's show Success Message. Sometimes App icon closed unfortunatl. But App will run continuous Try / click.

Comment: Works only if AVD or emulator is running. Start AVD or emulator before executing `./adb install FileName.apk`

Comment: This needs to be corrected so people understand the irrelevance of the apk location. They are probably accidentally getting adb in the path by going to the tools or platform-tools directory.

Comment: getting this error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]

Comment: @IAmAndroid  because you are using an APK file for a different architecture. Search google for more. (That was an old comment but replying because it might help others)

Comment: i learnt new thing today, install app on emulator while draging apk to emulator , wow great :)

Comment: I had a problem with Drag & Drop installation but I have discovered something. If I rename apk installation file to shorted form and then use Drag & Drop everything works fine.

Comment: On MAC OS works perfect for me:
adb install theapkfilename.apk

Thank you! Great Feedback!

Comment: On Windows: Use `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb install \path\to\build.apk`

Comment: i was testing this on huawei cloud debugging.
adb install was showing no progress.
Took a lot of time but finally installed for drag and drop option.

Answer (score 134):

If you've created more than one emulators or if you have an Android device plugged in, adb will complain with

```
error: more than one device and emulator
```

`adb help` is not extremely clear on what to do:

```
-d                        - directs command to the only connected USB device...
-e                        - directs command to the only running emulator...
-s <serial number>        ...
-p <product name or path> ...
```

The flag you decide to use has to come **before** the actual adb command:

```
adb -e install path/to/app.apk
```

Comment: Good stuff. Just to be clear: it's about how many emulators are *running* (not created) while executing `adb install`. Using `-s <serial number>` to unequivocally target a specific emulator bypasses this issue; the serial number can be gleaned from the output of `adb devices -l`.

Answer (score 95):

Nowadays, you can simply **drag and drop** the Android apk to the emulator and it will automatically starts installing.

Comment: Is there something you need to do to enable this?  Maybe it's different for the Visual Studio emulator, but drag and drop does not appear to work.

Comment: I have never used that one.

Comment: For others: drag and drop APK installs in Visual Studio Android Emulator do not work if the emulator was launched as Administrator.  Who knows why.

Comment: @chad Drag and drop from a lower privilege process to a higher privilege process is forbidden since Windows Vista. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/patricka/q-why-doesnt-drag-and-drop-work-when-my-application-is-running-elevated-a-mandatory-integrity-control-and-uipi

Comment: my emulator just hangs on installing apk; any idea why?

Answer (score 32):

Go to sdk folder, then go to tools.

Copy your apk file inside the tool directory

Run

```
./emulator -avd myEmulator
```

to run the emulator on mac. Then

```
./adb install myApp.apk
```

to install app on the emulator

Comment: it says ./adb No such file or directory in Mac, how should I run that ?

Comment: You need to type down your emulator name as it appears on ur eclipse. For instance ./emulator -avd youremulatorname

Comment: just thought I would share that in the latest android sdk-tools adb has moved from the tools folder to the platform-tools folder

Comment: there is no relevance of the tools or platform-tools directory except people are by luck getting adb in their paths.

Answer (score 28):

go to the android-sdk/tools directory in command prompt and then type

```
 adb install fileName.apk (Windows)

 ./adb install fileName.apk (Linux or Mac)
```

Answer (score 26):

Copy .apk file in your SDK's platform-tools/ directory,then install the .apk on the emulator by using cmd(on windows):

```
adb install <path_to_your_bin>.apk
```

or

```
./adb install <path_to_your_bin>.apk
```

**If there is more than one emulator running**,
you can find all running emulators by this command:

```
adb devices
```

or

```
./adb devices
```

then you must specify the emulator upon which to install the application, by its serial number, with the -s option. For example:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 install path/to/your/app.apk
```

or

```
./adb -s emulator-5554 install path/to/your/app.apk
```

Comment: It's also important that the `-s <emulator_name>` (for example, `-s emulator-5554`) comes before `install`.

In other words, `./adb install -s emulator-5554` would NOT work.

Answer (score 26):

First you need to install Android Studio on your machine. Then simply follow these steps.

1. Go to you navigation bar and open Android Studio. 
   [image]
2. From the toolbar open AVD Manager. (If you cannot see it create a new android project)
   [image]
3. Create a Virtual Device.
   [image]
4. Select a hardware device that you want to install your app.
   [image]
5. Select an android image that you want to install on your device. (If you cannot see any images you can download the require image from Recommended, x86 Images or Other images)
   [image]
6. Add a name to your AVD.
   [image]
7. Now the virtual device has been created and you can simply run it by clicking the play button.
   [image]
8. Now you have setup the virtual device and now you need to install the APK file.
   [image]
9. Download the APK file that you want to install and Drag and Drop it to the emulator. 
   [image]
10. The APK file has been successfully installed and you can see it in your applications. 
    [image]
11. Now you can simply run the installed app.
    [image]

Comment: At step 9, users who have not done this before might run into the problem solved at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617997

Answer (score 21):

**Drag and drop**

Simply drag-and-drop the apk file into your emulator.

[You can also run your android emulator without Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48729278/4221299).

Answer (score 14):

Download the Apk file from net and copy it to platform-tools of your SDK folder, then in command prompt go to that directory an type:

```
adb install filename.apk
```

press enter it will install in few seconds

Answer (score 13):

In Genymotion just drag and drop the *.apk file in to the emulator and it will automatically installs and runs.

http://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 12):

Download apk file from browser and then just click on it (notification area). Installation will start automatically.

Answer (score 11):

Goto Shell/Terminal/, reach at **android-sdk/tools directory** then

```
adb install fileName.apk // (u can run this command on windows)
or 
./adb install fileName.apk  //( u can run this command on linux)
```

Answer (score 10):

Let's suppose you have to install Facebook APK on your emulator.

You can use adb to install the APK to the running emulator in **OS X** like this:

```
./adb install ~/FBAndroid-2.1.apk
```

And on **Windows**, like this:

```
adb install %HOMEPATH%\FBAndroid-2.1.apk
```

Once complete, check the apps screen of the emulator to check that the app has been installed correctly. If you need to force the upgrade of this app from a previous version, add the -r flag, like this on **OS X**:

```
./adb install -r ~/FBAndroid-2.1.apk
```

Answer (score 8):

keep your emulator up and running.
In the command line, go inside the platform-tools folder, in your sdk folder which come with adt bundle and execute following command :

```
>adb install <yourFilename.apk>
```

This  command detect your running emulator/emulators and show you the list of devices where you can install this app(show if any physical device/devices connected to your computer.). Then you can select any one, if only one emulator is running then app will directly installed on it by default.

Note: For above command your .apk file needs to be in same directory.

for more detailed tutorial follo : [This link](http://blog.kerul.net/2012/08/how-to-install-apk-files-on-android.html)

Answer (score 8):

Just drag and drop your apk to emulator

Comment: This does not work anymore for me

Answer (score 7):

From Windows 7 Onwards ,

Shift + Right click in your apk file folder.

Select Open Command Window Here

Type & Hit "adb install AppName.apk"

Answer (score 7):

Drag and drop ".apk" file into the emulator window.

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37943159).

Answer (score 5):

(TESTED ON MACOS)

The first step is to run the emulator

> > emulator -avd < avd_name>

then use adb to install the .apk

> > adb install < path to .apk file>

If adb throws error like APK already exists or something alike. Run the adb shell while emulator is running

> > adb shell
> >
> > cd data/app
> >
> > adb uninstall < apk file without using .apk>

If adb and emulator are commands not found do following

**export PATH=$PATH://android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools://android-sdk-macosx/android-sdk-macosx/tools:**

For future use put the above line at the end of .bash_profile

> > vi ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 5):

if use more than one emulator at firs use this command

```
adb devices
```

and then chose amulatur and install application

```
adb -s "EMULATOR NAME" install "FILE PATH"
adb -s emulator-5556 install C:\Users\criss\youwave\WhatsApp.apk
```

Answer (score 5):

I might be wrong, but on Windows I simply drag and drop the `.apk` into Android Emulator. I mean, doing all mentioned above seems to be a lot of work.

Comment: Why post this answer if you are so unsure? Looks like you basically copied Amt87's answer.

Comment: I'm so unsure because i don't know if will work on his case. I can't see Amt87's answer.

Comment: Super easy. Way easier than other answers, and it works great on OS X.

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37943159).

Answer (score 4):

go to ADT/Android-sdk/tools directory in command prompt 
 1. adb install fileName.apk (Windows)

1. ./adb install fileName.apk (Ubuntu/Linux or Mac)

Answer (score 4):

**06-11-2020**

**Drag and Drop didn't work** for me on Windows 10 Pro.

1. Put the APK on Google Drive
2. Access that Google drive using Chrome browser on the Android Emulator
3. Then install it from there.

**Note:** You need to enable unknown sources within the Emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to create a app, which opens the apk file on the emulator. You have to copy the .apk file to the download folder of your emulator. Then replace yourAppName.apk with your .apk name.

here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "yourAppName.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
}
```

Comment: How is this best way?

Answer (score 2):

(1) You can also use gradle commands to install your APK while choosing the product and  flavor (Debug or Release).
See this Guide.

```
./gradlew assembleDebug (Incase you don't have the APK generated)


./gradlew installDebug
```

Incase you want a fresh install, you can remove any earlier installed builds on the device with below commands

```
./gradlew uninstallDebug
./gradlew installDebug
```

(2) You can also use the adb commands directly:

Setup adb for command line

```
export PATH=/Users/mayurik/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb:/Users/mayurik/Library/Android/sdk/tool
```

Command line ADB install

```
adb -d install pathto/sample.apk (on device)
adb -e install pathto/sample.apk (on emulator)
```

Also check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#directingcommands) here

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554 device
emulator-5555 device

$ adb -s emulator-5555 install helloWorld.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

you write the command on terminal/cmd
adb install FileName.apk.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps :

1. make sure you have allowed installation from unknown sources in
   settings.
2. Use the Android Device Monitor to copy the APK to the sdcard.
3. Use the builtin browser in Android to navigate to
   file:///sdcard/apk-name.apk
4. When the notification "Download complete" appears, click it.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can just drag and drop the apk in emulator and it will install!

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37943159).

Answer (score 1):

**On Linux** I do this:

1. first see which devices I currently have: `emulator -list-avds`
2. build the release `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`
3. install it at the emulated device "Nexus5" (you are inside the *android* directory, else use the full path to apk): `adb -s '8e138a9c' install  app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk`

Thats it. You can also use `./gradlew installRelease`

Answer (score 0):

Simple You can upload APK to file hosting or [download APK](https://apkdownloadmirror.com/) and use browser to install from unknown source .

Answer (score 0):

1) **paste the myapp.apk in platform-tools folder** , in my case C:\Users\mazbizxam\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools, this is the link in my case it may change to you people

2)**open the directory in CMD** CD C:\Users\mazbizxam\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

3)Now you are in platform-tools folder , just type **adb install myapp.apk**

please ensure that your emulator is turn on , if every thing is ok apk will install

Answer (score 0):

> Start the console (Windows XP), Run -> type cmd, and move to the
>   platform-tools folder of SDK directory.

In case anyone wondering how to run `cmd` in `platform-tools` folder of SDK directory, if you are running a new enough version of Windows, follow the steps:

1. Go to `platform-tools` through Windows Explorer.
2. While holding `shift` right click and you will find the option "Open Command window here".
3. Click on it and cmd will start in that folder.

[image]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Late, but to be completed with options here:
A handy tool to install any apk via gui to a running emulator is:
http://apkinstaller.com

This can directly connect to a running instance via adb and can successfully install any kind of apk packages.

Maybe this is also helpful for other people. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can try build and run application manually

- build `View -> Tool Windows -> Build Variants`
- run `Tasks -> install -> install<build_varaiant>`
- open `adb shell am start -n <package_name>/.<activity_name>`

[[more]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49075932/4770877)

Answer (score -1):

In mac or windows . Just run the emulator and Drag and drop the apk on the home screen . It will install

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37943159).

Comment: This doesn't always work.

Answer (score -1):

Just drag and drop apk file in the emulator and done....

Comment: Add some more details to your answer. Else it is just like a comment and is considered low quality.

Comment: Run your emulator and drag and paste your apk file in it ,it will automatically install apk and onclicking the icon it will run the application

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37943159).

Comment: And it doesn't always work.  So... [not] done.

Answer (score -1):

You can click a button in the menu of the emulator window that says "Install External APK." It will then prompt you to enter the location of the APK or choose it in a file browser. Select the file then click install and it will install it to the emulator's device.