# How to run .APK file on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, apk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you install an APK file in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator)

I download an APK file and I want to run it on an Android emulator but I don't know how.  Please help me.  Thanks!

Comment: Best answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3480235/1318946

Comment: Open your emulator....drag and drop the .apk file to your emulator...it worked for me!!!

Comment: Great suggestion @AkhileshSinha. Drag and drop worked for me even on Microsoft's Android Emulator. It can't be any simpler than this :). I wonder why would anyone use any other method but drag and drop.

Comment: None of these answers or comments seem to say how to "run" the apk on the emulator. They all only talk about installing it, which is an entirely different thing.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Steps (These apply for Linux. For other OS, visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator/3480235#3480235)) -

1. Copy the apk file to `platform-tools` in `android-sdk linux` folder.
2. Open **Terminal** and **navigate to platform-tools** folder in **android-sdk**.
3. Then Execute this command -

   > ./adb install FileName.apk
4. If the operation is successful (the result is displayed on the screen), then you will find your file in the launcher of your emulator.

For more info can check this link : [android videos](http://android-videos.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Anyway to do this through eclipse?

Comment: Use ```./adb install -r FileName.apk```
If the app is already installed or you are prototyping something, this will re-install as well

Comment: there's no reason to copy the apk to platform-tools

Comment: for osx if you installed via Android Studio, the platform-tools folder is in `~/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: Will it work if you don't do step 1 and just provide an absolute path?

Comment: No need to copy the apk to platform-tools, you can set `adb` as your global environment variable and use adb directly from **command line**, just navigate to folder containing apk and use the install command. 
`adb install filename.apk`

Comment: I am getting an error about having multiple devices, what's the device switch?

Answer (score 69):

You need to install the APK on the emulator.  You can do this with the `adb` command line tool that is included in the Android SDK.

```
adb -e install -r yourapp.apk
```

Once you've done that you should be able to run the app.

The `-e` and `-r` flags might not be necessary.  They just specify that you are using an emulator (if you also have a device connected) and that you want to replace the app if it already exists.

Comment: i want to try in on emulator and not on device , so where i should copy apk file on pc ?

Comment: @mahdi That command is for installing on the emulator.  Start the emulator and run that command.  It doesn't matter where the .apk file is stored, it will be copied to the emulator.

Comment: this message shown on command line "Permission denide"

Comment: how can i be root user in android command line ?

Comment: I don't know why you get that error.  Perhaps it's a permissions problem with the emulator files?  Did you install it as the same user that you are running the adb command with?

Comment: In addition to this answer, if you need to install it on a specific emulator, you can use: `adb -s emulator-5554 -e install -r yourapp.apk` where `emulator-5554` is the name of the emulator instance (it's in the titlebar after you run the emulator)

Comment: `adb -s emulator-5554 install yourapp.apk` also works

Comment: +1 for including and explaining -e and -r flags.

Comment: Helpful as it seems like it should work, but a certificate error of some kind kept it from working for me.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch Do you have the text of the error? It will refuse to replace an APK with one signed with a different certificate. If you want to do that you need to uninstall the old APK first.

Comment: New to Android development - what is the adb command? It's not recognized on windows, and I have little dev experience on a non-unix cmd line

Comment: @jdero It's the Android Debug Bridge (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) tool. If you have installed the Android SDK I would expect it to be present on Windows but I'm not a Windows user (perhaps it's just not on your path?).

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the case. Thanks for the ref.

Comment: Is it possible to install application in emulator using play store ? I can't find it in emulator.

Answer (score 22):

Start an Android Emulator (make sure that all supported APIs are included when you created the emulator, we needed to have the Google APIs for instance).

Then simply email yourself a link to the .apk file, and download it directly in the emulator, and click the downloaded file to install it.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer gave me an idea; i just put my apk file inside the phone and ran it. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

Step-by-Step way to do this:

1. Install Android SDK
2. Start the emulator by going to $SDK_root/emulator.exe
3. Go to command prompt and go to the directory $SDK_root/platform-tools (or else add the path to windows environment)
4. Type in the command adb install
5. Bingo. Your app should be up and running on the emulator