# Can I run an APK file in the Android emulator?

Tags: android, apk

Can I run an APK file in the Android emulator? I have to look at the UI design of an application, but only the apk is provided.

Comment: See here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512458/androidhow-to-run-apk-file-on-emulator and here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can run apk in the emulator . for that you need to install apk in emulator ..

### Steps To Install APK in Emulator

- Open Command Prompt
- Now Go to tools or platform-tools . Ex(E:\android-sdk\tools)
- Then type this command adb install [apk file name whenever it stored]

Comment: Thanks 4 ur description!! Really helped

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have an emulator created and started (which you can do with the AVD manager,) you can install an apk by running:

```
adb install WhateverApp.apk
```

from the terminal. The `adb` command comes with the SDK and is under `platform-tools/`. Then just run it in the emulator.

Comment: in case you also have a device connected, issue the command `adb install -e whateverapp.apk`