# Is it possible to run the .apk file on android/emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk

I got an APK from the Internet.

Can I install and run the APK on the emulator?

If yes, how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512458/androidhow-to-run-apk-file-on-emulator

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you install an APK file in the Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes it is possible**

first copy that .apk file into "platform-tools" folder of your android-SDK then open the command prompt and go to "platform-tools" folder now type "adb install ***_***" here underline means your .apk file name. then press enter. it's DONE

Be sure that your emulator is running.

Answer (score 3):

Use `adb` to install apk on emulator (or any connected device as well):

```
adb install file.apk
```

Re-install, keeping application data:

```
adb install -r file.apk
```

`adb` documentation is available here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Answer (score 1):

### Yes you can.

Easiest way is to download the apk file from within the browser on the emulator, then install it from the notifications menu.

Alternatively, you can install the Android SDK (which you might already have done if you have the emulator) and use `adb install my.apk` which should install to any available device (so long as only one is available). Use `adb devices` to check what devices are available - when you run the emulator, it should show up there.

**N.B.** you will need to enable `unknown sources` in the applications menu of settings for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Place it in your host and download the .apk file from your emulator browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Place your *.apk* file in the **platform-tools** folder of **SDK**, go to command prompt (path to ADB) and run the following command:

```
adb install your_apk_file.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work, but try to open the File Explorer of the emulator through DDMS perspective in Eclipse, and copy/paste your apk in a folder. Then navigate to that folder from your emulator and launch the apk.