# How to run avd outside of eclipse with only apk?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, android-virtual-device

I want to show my app to some people who arent programmers and dont have android phones. I presume the only way to do this would be to use an AVD, but since they arent programmers I dont want them to go through eclipse. So the question is, how do I set up an AVD to run outside of eclipse off just the apk?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512458/androidhow-to-run-apk-file-on-emulator

Answer (score 0):

oh, The best way is google.

- make sure the Android SDK is installed before starting.
- "$PATH/android create avd" to create an AVD or "$PATH/android list" to check the existed AVD.you can use "$PATH/android help" to get other API command.
- use "emulator -avd avdname" to start an AVD. or "emulator -help" to get other api.
- use "$PATH/adb help" to get adb API command.
- use adb API command to control apk life-cycle.