# How to work with android studio along side with Unity 3D

Tags: android-studio, unity3d-editor

I 'm just getting started with Unity 3D and I 'm going through android games development learning and I wonder how to setup Unity to work with android studio ?

Answer (score 0):

For the majority of your tasks, you will not be working in Android Studio.  You will be working directly in Unity.  The only reason you would need to work in Android Studio would be to create [**native plug-ins**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html) for additional functionality that is not provided in the Unity Engine.

A detailed description of the requirements to build for Android are available in [**the Unity3D documentation**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html).  An abbreviated description:

- When you are ready to test on your device, you will build for Android: **File>Build Settings, and select Android from the list**
- You will need to have the **Android SDK** installed, and have at least one **API Level** installed using the Android **SDK Manager** (minimum).
- In **Edit>Project Settings>Player Settings**, open **Other Settings**. Choose the **Minimum API Level** for your game.  This API level must be installed using the Android **SDK Manager**
- Finally, When you've finished building, you will have a **.APK** file.

  - You can copy to your Android device, and install with a file manager. *-OR-*
  - You can [**install it on an Android Emulator.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512458/androidhow-to-run-apk-file-on-emulator)

I hope this helps in some way!