# Android strace in Real device

Tags: android, linux, perl, android-emulator, strace

I have the following situation, I want to monitor the system calls on Android phones so
I made an script to do that. With Android Emulator works perfectly (writes the traces of the application in a specific file on my Ubuntu).
The problem is when I attach a real phone to analyze it, it says the following in the result file:

```
ptrace attach failed: Operation not permitted
```

I'm using this code to get it, but I don't understand why it works on the emulator and not in the  rooted real device.

This is the comand I use in perl:

```
system("$dirTools/adb -s $Device shell strace -p $PID[1]>$dirRecordDataSet/$Date/$appName &");
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely you need root access to do that call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maye be the adb daemon runs with limited privilege. You can try to install strace with setuid roo. Here is manpage advice about it :

> Setuid Installation
>
> If strace is installed setuid to root
>   then the invoking user will be able to
>   attach to and trace processes owned by
>   any user. In addition setuid and
>   setgid programs will be executed and
>   traced with the correct effective
>   privileges. Since only users trusted
>   with full root privileges should be
>   allowed to do these things, it only
>   makes sense to install strace as
>   setuid to root when the users who can
>   execute it are restricted to those
>   users who have this trust. For
>   example, it makes sense to install a
>   special version of strace with mode
>   'rwsr-xr--', user root and group
>   trace, where members of the trace
>   group are trusted users. If you do use
>   this feature, please remember to
>   install a non-setuid version of strace
>   for ordinary lusers to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can install your APK file to `Android emulator` by following answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator). After installation,

Go to Eclipse, Open `DDMS` view from Windows => Open Perspective.

Go to `File Browser` tab, click on any folder, and Click on 'Push a file to a device'. You can upload any empty trace.txt file here. I would recommend you put your file in sdcard folder.

Go to CMD as given in the above link. Type `adb shell`. Go to sdcard by typing `cd sdcard`.

Now type `ps` on the command line and find out PID of your APK file via its package name.

Now type `strace -p <pid> -o trace.txt`. All system calls will be placed in this file. When you want to finish stracing your APK, you can download this trace.txt file to your computer and see the traces.