# 'strace' in android

Tags: java, android, linux, strace

I want to produce application that analyzes the system calls that occur within Android.
Information about the system call attempts to collect by using the Linux debugging tool called strace.
However, strace is not a built-in program for android sdk.
How can I use strace from my Android application? Please help me.

(Please note that not unfamiliar with the English language. Thank you.)

Comment: You want to run the tracing on the device? Check the related links to the right, e.g.
[Android strace in Real device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144967/android-strace-in-real-device).

Comment: Thank you.I learned a lot, thanks to this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the device must be rooted.

In this link you can download a strace for android.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2516002

download and move it to /system/bin and set permissions to 755.

Check in adb shell screen.

Now, over all the preparations. In adb shell screen, check the strace command.

Comment: The link given above points to [https://redirect.viglink.com/?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_150269630884814&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&libId=j6bufb9w01000n4o000DAnviqpzfxg1m9&loc=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D2516002&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fd-h.st%2F7fo&title=%5BUTILITY%5D%20STrace%204.8%20-%20Ultimate%20debugging%20ut%E2%80%A6%20%7C%20Android%20Development%20and%20Hacking&txt=%3Cb%3E%20Download%20Strace%204.8%20from%20here%20%3C%2Fb%3E]
Which is a spam !