# install delphi app on android mobile phone OS =2.3.6

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I run some trial runs using delphi XE5 with mobile support for android OS.  My mobile device is android version 2.3.6.  I know that the usb debugger support is only available with version 4.x of android. Anyhow, can I install my compiler app with Delphi XE 5 on Android my manual copying of files to my mobile phone?

Which file do I have to take from my computer and install somewhere on the mobile phone ?

Comment: You have an *apk* file, right?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Deploying_Your_Unsigned_Android_Application

Comment: Are you sure your Android 2.x has an ARMv7 based processor with NEON support? Being that old an Android version, there's a big chance it won't have the proper processor support to allow Delphi compiled programs to run. Download https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.syscheck and check it.

Comment: syscheck reported arm7 with neon support, OS = android 2.3.6

Comment: The link I gave you tells you how to find the file you need to put on your device (the info is the same for a signed app, except you ignore the part about a missing signature file in the text in the link). If you can allow non-Google Play apps, you can email the .apk file to your device and then run it from your email client to install, or just copy it to a folder you can access and run it with a file manager. (I use Astro File Manager on Jelly Bean, and just copy the files into a "transfer" folder via a USB connection from Windows.)

Comment: with delphi I#m fine ... I have the  .apk file :-), but now struggling with the mobile device LG smart phone, not sure where to create the transfer folder . did not yet run e mail on this phone, direct copy via usb is the way i want to go

Comment: copy the delphi app.apk file  to a folder on the phone .apk, but this deleted the installed app icons :-(

Comment: Once you have the *apk* file, you can install it with the Android debugger: [Install an apk file from command prompt?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7076240/33732) I don't know what you mean about it being unavailable before Android 4.0; it's the tool I used to manipulate my phone, and my phone doesn't support 4.0 at all.

Answer (score 2):

According to David InterSimone the [following versions of Android are supported](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/davidi/2013/09/13/42863):

```
there must be a GPU
the CPU must be ARMv7 with NEON instruction support

the OS on the target device must be one of:
GingerBread: Android 2.3.3+ (MR1 or later), which is API level 10
Ice Cream Sandwich: Android 4.0.3+ (MR1 or later), which is API level 15
Jelly Bean: Android 4.1+ (release, MR1, MR2 or later), 
  which are API levels 16, 17 and 18
```

So your version is not the issue.
And your CPU is also OK. 
You still need to check that the phone has a GPU.

As per Ken's comment, here how to find and deploy the apk file:
 http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Deploying_Your_Unsigned_Android_Application

Comment: DavidI was quoting from my blog post there - I thought I recognised the MR references :o)