# How To Install Android Applications (APK file) on Android x-86 Version 5.1 (Lollipop)

Tags: android, installation, apk, emulation, android-5.0-lollipop

I have installed the Android x-86 version 5.1 on VM-ware and my android can reach to the internet connection. 
Here, I cannot use play store, so that I use the APK mirror to download the android applications using web browser Chrome, e.g. Line, Zalo, Viber and etc.

After I have downloaded the android application, I cannot install it, when I open the file at Folder Download, it cannot be opened.

How do I install the android application on Android x-86 version 5.1?

Answer (score 0):

There are **cmd command** to Install APK through **adb**.

[Install an apk file from command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076240/install-an-apk-file-from-command-prompt) Maybe it helps you.

Comment: Hi... do you mean, i have to use terminal emulator on android x-86? Then, I just simply use this code "adb install example.apk". for instance, i wanna install instagram so i just have to type ---> adb install instagram.apk? Is it okay if the file still located at Folder Download? I don't need to use another software right? Thanks a lot for your help :).

Comment: Your welcome. Deni,the best way I did was shifting my apk to adb folder or you have to manual direct there.

Comment: Welcome and Thanks with a upvote developer would get encouragement ;)

Comment: His Sir, i have some doubts regarding problem to resolve DNS server. before I added this command on terminal emulator, ndc network create 100
ndc network interface add 100 eth0
ndc network route add 100 eth0 <GATEWAY>/24
ndc network route add 100 eth0 0.0.0.0/0 <DNS1> <DNS2>
ndc resolver setnetdns 100 localdomain <DNS1> <DNS2>
ndc network default set 100. Then I can access internet. but when I shutdown and open again my android x-86 via vm-ware, i cannot access again the internet. further, i add that command into /etc/init.sh and I reboot. however, i cannot access internet. please help me

Comment: Deni,I have no idea for network issue in your x-86 via vm-ware.But I recommend so hardly to use **Geny Motion Emulator**.Signup free and use it.