# How to solve, "app-debug.apk does not exist on disk. Error while Installing APK", this error in Android?

Tags: android, android-install-apk

[image]02/05 22:07:49: Launching app

**The APK file... \app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk does not exist on disk. Error while Installing APK**

I have tried cleaning, rebuilding as well as refreshing all gradle project, restarting pc and android studio ; but nothing working any above these solutions.

*How can I solve this error? My app app is not going to run on my device...*

Comment: Do you have Antivirus or something that'll scan that APK file and delete it after you build the app?

Comment: yes, I am using quick heal anti-virus from last 6 months.

Comment: Try disabling it. See if you can install the app

Comment: I have tried the installation of app on my device, after disabling and removing the Antivirus... but still getting the same error. :(

Comment: Okay, so can you go to that folder in the file browser? Does it really exist? Try to watch the folder when you build the app

Comment: yes, "app-debug.apk" is present in this "..\app\build\outputs\apk" apk package.

Comment: Are you comfortable using the `adb` command line to install the APK file?

Comment: I don't know about how to install the apk file on our device using command  line...

Comment: I am using the shift+f10 key for the purpose of running the app

Comment: Won't necessarily fix the error, but it's an option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076240/install-an-apk-file-from-command-prompt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The APK file does not exist on disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039834/the-apk-file-does-not-exist-on-disk)

Comment: means?? didn't get

Comment: okey okey......

Comment: Now, It is giving me above error message... see the screenshot

Comment: Yeah, read the duplicate post. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40634910/2308683

Comment: Thanks brother, it's work for me... you saved my day.