# Apk Not installing in Real Device

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I Have started my new android project with Basic Default Activity.IT run fine in emulator .I Have tried to install iy in real device both pre lolipop and abovr lolipop device but getting error
App cannot be installed error in  prelolipop device and above lolipop device app will install but when i try to open app it will close

Can any one help how to fix this issue ?

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Post crash LogCat..

Comment: Can i see the exact error message

Comment: When click on install application it will show error as X Application not installed

Comment: yes but then click the "event log" tab in the lower right corner and copy and paste the red message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine, my guess is that your **APK** is not completely built

> Build your APK:
>
> 1. On Android Studio click on **Build**
> 2. Then click on **Build APK(s)**

After that search for your debug APK and install it on your device

If this fails you can try **ADB**, take a look at the following guides for install and usage:

- [How to install it on windows](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/)
- [How to Install apk using ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7076679/7355128)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Two things could be the problem.

1. Navigate to settings > security and make sure Unknown sources is checked.
2. Make sure you downloaded the whole apk in the email

Hope this helps!

Comment: please make sure about question before answering of that.