# Build and deploy Xamarin to an emulator through command line

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I’m building a xamarin android app using visual studio community edition 2019 on windows. Inside visual studio gui I am able to build and deploy to android emulator. I’m willing to do this without using the gui, through command line . I understand msbuild can build. May I know the command to start the emulator and deploy the app?

Comment: maybe you could use `adb install` to deploy .apk to the device

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. I came up with a script which you could find below in my answer. If you find time, please review the script

Answer (score 2):

Steps to Build & Deploy to Android through the command line (replace `Sample` with your project name):

1. In your terminal/command line, run this `msbuild Sample.Android/Sample.Android.csproj /verbosity:normal /t:Rebuild /t:PackageForAndroid /t:SignAndroidPackage /p:Configuration=Debug`
2. Then, change directory using `cd Sample.Android/bin/Debug` to find the the signed APK file,
3. Using [ADB(Android Debug Bridge)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development#connecting-over-wifi), install it to your device/emulator with this command `adb install com.tfp.sample-Signed.apk`, [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076240/install-an-apk-file-from-command-prompt/7076679#7076679).

I have written a more [detailed explanation over here](https://blog.devgenius.io/build-xamarin-apps-with-vs-code-to-m1-macs-iphones-android-11bc158f3773?sk=bc296c444465642b9d5771aef3f5e731).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner batch scrip writer. So feel free to correct this:). This scripts work for me to build the xamarin visual studio project, start the emulator and deploy the apk. I have two batch files, the second one runs in parallel with the first one.

cmd.bat:

```
"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" start-server
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="any cpu" /v:m "E:\App2\App2.sln"

@echo off

if %ERRORLEVEL%% == 0 (
start /min call "E:\App2\Build Commands\install.bat" ""
"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE" -no-boot-anim -avd lollypop -prop monodroid.avdname=lollypop
exit
) else (
pause
)
```

install.bat:

```
"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" wait-for-device
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" -r /t:Install /v:m "E:\App2\App2.Android\App2.Android.csproj" /p:AdbTarget=-e
@echo off

if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 exit else pause
```