# How to debug And deploy app to emulator from command line - MAUI

Tags: .net, visual-studio, cmd, command-line-interface, maui

I am executing MAUI application to emulator (or device) from Command Prompt. It deploy app to emulator but it is not debugging project in Visual Studio. In Command Prompt First I am setting project directory and using below command

```
dotnet build -t:Run -f net7.0-android
```

How can I debug and deploy app from Visual Studio using Command Prompt?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this case: [Build and deploy Xamarin to an emulator through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705684/build-and-deploy-xamarin-to-an-emulator-through-command-line). For more info about deployment you can see the official doc: [Publish an Android app using the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli).