# When building an apk for my samsung using buildozer an error occurs

Tags: ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

I don't know if the fault is in my python code or with buildozer so just ask if you need my python code! :).

When I run `buildozer android debug deploy run` , buildozer ran for about 10 minutes and worked perfectly. It then shows the list of device attached and my device. 
After that the following error code occurs:

```
adb: failed to install /home/casper/Desktop/myapp/bin/SNapp__armeabi-v7a-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk: Performing Streamed Install
# Command failed: /home/casper/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb install -r "/home/casper/Desktop/myapp/bin/SNapp__armeabi-v7a-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk"
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/casper-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1893,unix/casper-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1893'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'nl_NL.UTF-8'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     LC_NAME = 'nl_NL.UTF-8'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'nl_NL.UTF-8'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1789'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     PWD = '/home/casper/Desktop/myapp'
#     LOGNAME = 'casper'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     HOME = '/home/casper'
#     USERNAME = 'casper'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LC_PAPER = 'nl_NL.UTF-8'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5802'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/db6f1194_4972_4a9d_819e_d8a96b4eabe5'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '34f126e8f07c49ffbd6e1616b34ccf1c'
#     MANAGERPID = '1623'
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'nl_NL.UTF-8'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'casper'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.121'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'nl_NL.UTF-8'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'nl_NL.UTF-8'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=2084db657da8b8b6412aef725e1720e2'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     LC_TIME = 'nl_NL.UTF-8'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:24887'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/casper/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/casper/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=2084db657da8b8b6412aef725e1720e2'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'nl_NL.UTF-8'
#     _ = '/home/casper/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/casper/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/casper/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/casper/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r20b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#     ANDROID_SERIAL = 'ce011711d2a3c20103'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

How can I fix this error?
Thanks in advance!

edit:
Above the error I found another warning that may be relevant:

```
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
```

Comment: What happens when you run the install outside buildozer?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076240/install-an-apk-file-from-command-prompt

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now the app is on my mobile, but when I open it, it immediately crashes. The same happens when I open the app using the kivy launcher so I don't think this is a buildozer error, or am I wrong? Any suggestion in what direction I can search for the cause of the crash?

Comment: It's possible to debug the standardoutput https://en.droidwiki.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge#Logcat

Comment: When I read the log, I noticed the following error: ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests``` . When I run my python program in python everything works fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: Missing modules could be an issue with python for android, think you have to search for errors in the build process