# How to resolve App Installation issue on Samsung A9 Pro

Tags: android, installation, samsung-mobile

I am trying to install an APK which is downloaded from my organization's internal app store. Download is successful but each time the installation gets stuck midway. Tried clearing the cache from play store, resetting app preferences, allowed installation from unknown source, still the issue remains unsolved!

Can anyone please help me with the issue? Please note i am able to install the other Apks from the same store.

Comment: What does the installer says on screen ? have you tried installing it with [adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076240/install-an-apk-file-from-command-prompt)?

Comment: No error message comes on screen. Installation just gets stuck. One of our users is facing this issue, so running through studio or through adb is not possible.