# Create new blank space on home screen : Android

Tags: android, generate

i couldnt find anything on google and it being hard to describe:

Android App Studio allows you to create an own App with its functions etc. i can then run the app on my own phone by connecting it with android studio. Android Studio then creates a new app on my phone with the app's title and a default icon and starts the app automatically.
**My question is** how is the app generated on my phone? Where is the function/codeline for android phones that generates an app?

Hope i can find answers here, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not really get what you want to ask. But if you wonder how Android Studio can create a new application on your phone. Then it have a thing names `ADB` as a bridge to communicate to the phone and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app isn't generated on phone, Android Studio builds it using [Gradle build system](https://developer.android.com/studio/build) and sideload it to device using [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb). more info how you can push APK to device from your pc/laptop you can find [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076240/install-an-apk-file-from-command-prompt)