# How to run apk from commandline in emulator

Tags: android, command-line, emulation

How do I start an apk on the emulator from the console? I wasn't able to find the correct command.

I have an Ubuntu running in a VM and there the emulator. I now try to install (adb install App.apk -works!) and run it from commandline.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you install an APK file in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

to install:

```
adb -e install -r "your-apk-file-complete-path"
```

Now to run:

```
am [start|instrument]
am start [-a <action>] [-d <data_uri>] [-t <mime_type>]
[-c <category> [-c <category>] ...]
[-e <extra_key> <extra_value> [-e <extra_key> <extra_value> ...]
[-n <component>] [-D] [<uri>]
am instrument [-e <arg_name> <arg_value>] [-p <prof_file>]
[-w] <component>
```

sample launch code

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n
com.abhi.ui/com.abhi.ui.LaunchIt
```

Comment: I needed to type like this: adb shell am start... (on v1.0.29)

Answer (score 3):

Nicely described here: http://www.android.pk/blog/general/launch-app-through-adb-shell/

Comment: The action argument isn't really needed in most cases unless you want to start your application by using some specific action. The -n (Component) argument should be enough in most cases.

Comment: The link is dead. Please avoid adding links as a answer