# How to execute a file from any type programmatically in android?

Tags: android

How to execute a file from any type programmatically in android ?

I'm using the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
File file = new File(parent.getItemAtPosition().toString());
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
startActivity(intent);
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by running .apk files see this([How to run apk from commandline in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605821/how-to-run-apk-from-commandline-in-emulator).And) run those commands from your code.

Comment: no actually what i need is to prompt the user to select any file from the Sd-card either pdf,video,image etc .. and just opening it after selecting it from a list view for instance

Answer (score 0):

> How to execute a file from any type programmatically in android ?

By definition, this is impossible.

First, your code does not "execute a file". *Programs* are executed. Files are *viewed*.

Second, not all files are meant to be viewed, insofar as there may not exist any sort of viewer for them.

If you call `setType()` on the `Intent`, with the proper MIME type for the file, you will increase the odds that Android will be able to find a viewer activity. There is [a `MimeTypeMap` utility class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html) that will help you find a likely MIME type for the file extension of the file, though it certainly does not cover all MIME types.