# not able to run android map application on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I tried executing an android app to display the google map. when i run the code the following error appears on the emulator.
Google Play Services, which some of your applications rely on, is not supported by your device. please contact the manufacturer for assistance.
please guide me to run the application successfully

Comment: you can't run map application in emulator because emulator doesn't have `googleplay services` installed.

Comment: what are the other means of testing the application other than installing the .apk file on the device?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459338/how-to-run-google-map-api-v2-on-android-emulator/18459530#18459530  It might help you.

Comment: this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358535/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-alert/19492412#19492412

Answer (score 0):

You can successful install Google Maps v2 on an emulator using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13869332#13869332).
You should do the following steps:
    Create a new emulator Nexus S, Android 2.3.3. Don't use Google API.

Install [com.android.vending.apk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8jiban3pq2cgkvo/com.android.vending-108b71f4793186b8fd1768a9cd19bbd5.apk) (Google Play Store, v.3.10.9)

Install [com.google.android.gms.apk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3blse4z3l2et96/com.google.android.gms-6413100ccfca460007fdc988b1363db8.apk) (Google Play Service, v.2.0.12)

Test with this configuration on Android SDK Tools 22.0.1. Other configuration that target pure Android not the google one should work to.

```
Device: Galaxy Nexus
Target: Android 4.2.2 - API Level 17
CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabi-v7a)
Checked: Use Host GPU


Open the AVD

Execute this in the terminal / cmd

adb -e install com.google.android.gms.apk
adb -e install com.android.vending.apk
```

**commands for ubuntu:**

adb -e install -r com.google.android.gms.apk

adb -e install -r com.android.vending.apk

Dont forgot to give exact path of your apk file inside command.

```
Restart the AVD
```

Comment: where do i run these commands on linux? on the normal ubuntu terminal? and how to install these?

Comment: Which Operating system you are using??

Comment: i am currently using ubuntu 12.04 is there any path that i need to follow and install?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605821/how-to-run-apk-from-commandline-in-emulator