# Android Can anyone suggest me how to create apk from command line step by step?

Tags: android

My Requirement to create the .apk from my code without using android studio and eclipse.
My code is on svn.

Comment: may be duplicate check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605821/how-to-run-apk-from-commandline-in-emulator

Comment: no that is different and my requirement is different.

Comment: ok yes you want to make an apk . and link is about to run apk.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Apache ANT. You can download it from here: [Apache ANT Home Page](http://ant.apache.org/)

Follow [this](https://www.built.io/blog/2012/07/building-android-applications-apk-from-the-command-line/) link here to get everything set up to use ANT.

Once you have ANT installed and setup, navigate to your project folder and type

```
ant release
```

This will create a debug release for you to test on a real device. 
If you would like, you can configure the Android build script to automatically sign and align your application package. To do so, you must provide the path to your keystore and the name of your key alias in your project’s ant.properties file. With this information provided, the build script will prompt you for your keystore and alias password when you build in release mode and produce your final application package, which will be ready for distribution.

To specify your keystore and alias, open the project ant.properties file (found in the root of the project directory) and add entries for key.store and key.alias as below

```
key.store=<App-Name>.keystore
key.alias=Alias-Name
```

Save your changes then type this in the command prompt

```
ant release
```

Enter your keystore and alias passwords when prompted.

More advanced info can be found [here](https://www.built.io/blog/2012/11/building-android-application-apk-from-the-command-line-v2/)

Comment: It's 2016, not 2012. Consider using gradle over ant.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add JAVA_HOME (Jdk path )
2. Add Ant path
3. Add sdk path

Then open command prompt set the location of your project,

> gradlew.bat assembleDebug

after building you can see apk at build location of your project.