# Android Emulator: Adding FireFox app?

Tags: android, firefox, android-emulator

We are trying to test our mobile web site on various Android simulators as we can't buy them all. We need to test it for Android Firefox as a requirement from the customer.

How can we install Mobile Firefox onto a Emulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So according to [this](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Platforms/Android) site, if you have a device *without* Android Market (i.e. your emulator), you can download it directly from their FTP server:

http://bit.ly/fennecftp

Of course you'll have to update it yourself, but for testing it should be fine. Then install it like any other apk file ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3480201/1101070)).