# Installing an apk on android emulator on Mac OS

Tags: android, macos, emulation, apk

I tried following these steps(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator)):

```
go to sdk folder, then go to tools.
copy your apk file inside the tool directory
./emulator -avd myEmulator
to run the emulator on mac 
./adb install myApp.apk
to install app on the emulator
```

But when I run "./emulator -avd phoneEmulator" (phoneEmulator is the name of my emulator)
it just displays:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:tools myName$ ./emulator -avd phoneEmulator
2012-07-30 22:44:33.377 emulator-arm[2859:80b] Warning once: This application, or a
library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. 
Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
```

It's as if that command is never returning.

If I can't input the 2nd command `./adb install myApp.apk` in that window, where do I call it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. Open Terminal
2. go to android-sdk-mac\platform-tools
3. type ./adb install myApp.apk

Answer (score 29):

You can work around by:

1. You have a *.apk file with you if you don't have, download it.
2. Open Android Studio and **Run the emulator**.
3. Open the **finder** and go to the **location** which **contains your *.apk file**.
4. **Drag that *.apk** and drop into the **emulator** and it will ask for confirmation after your confirmation it will install the *.apk in the emulator.
5. You can find it in application menu once installation succeeds.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: This answer should be at the top

Comment: Of course, it was drag and drop, it's a mac... Silly me...

Answer (score 20):

First of all, you SHOULD NOT copy APKs to the tools or any other SDK directory.
Do not `cd` to the SDK directories, just add them to the `PATH` environment var or use their absolute path in command lines.
Then, if you want to run the emulator and then execute command from the same terminal, send the process to background (&):

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/sdk/tools:path/to/sdk/platform-tools
$ emulator -avd myEmulator &
$ adb install /path/to/my.apk
```

Comment: Yes - rather surprising that no one made these points earlier.

Answer (score 5):

You can work around by:

1. Upload yourapp.apk to internet. I.e: yourhost.com/yourapp.apk
2. Run emulator
3. Open internet browser on your emulator, visit link yourhost.com/yourapp.apk
4. Download and install

Answer (score 0):

adb can be run from a seperate terminal once this emulator boots up.

Comment: When I do this ("./adb install BarcodeScanner4.2.apk") I get "-bash: ./adb: No such file or directory". Any ideas?

Comment: Did you cd to the location of adb? That message means that bash can't find "./adb"

Answer (score 0):

May Be, Useful to all the command in [MAC OS Terminal](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

Answer (score 0):

Am I the only one whose apps install in the emulator when I run them as Android Application from eclipse?

I mean - why go though the trouble of adb when you could just use eclipse? (unless you have something against eclipse!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [app](http://vitovalov.com/2015/04/12/apk-installer.html). It will install the apk by just double clicking on it after you create an association to .apk files. It's all explained in the github source.

Comment: This link is no longer available.

Comment: Now it's fixed @Petroff

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively You can use 'adb install' command as follows. "adbinstall/filename.apk"
ex. adb install /Users/manojclinberg/Downloads/ad3e0e46-d716-4fa9-b603-b8db3accf260.apk