# Android: Test if proguarded app is working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard

I want to use ProGuard to obfuscate my app (using Eclipse). Unfortunately ProGuard is only enabled when exporting the release version. Is there any way to test the proguarded build on the development machine since I don't own an android device? I use a lot of native code etc., so I want to get sure nothing essential gets optimized away.

Thank you

Comment: You can see the method to put a release APK on an emulator [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3480235/1565091