# Android Emulator - how to view file in Emulator which transfered from computer to emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I have pushed file in to emulator's sdcard from computer. I need to view that file in emulator. But the file is not listed. I dont know how to find its path. I mean we dont have something like "My files" in emulator. So how can we view the file? Pictures are getting listed in the gallary. But for other files? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is download a file explorer app apk ([here's](http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andexplorer/) where you can get one). Then follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator) instructions to install the apk on your emulator. Use that to explore files directly on your emulator.

Answer (score 5):

the DDMS view has a "File Explorer" tab. in it you will see the file structure. check `/mnt/sdcard` (or similar) for your file. there are icons that will allow you to Push and or Pull files to and from the emulator.

Comment: Yes. What I actually want is, I have pushed some files in to emulator through file explorer, I need to view that file in the emulator, not in the file explorer tab.

Comment: to OPEN() and READ() you mean??

Comment: To View the file in the emulator. We have "My Files" folder in the android device right? through which we ll view the files in the device know. I need that kind of thing in the emulator.

Comment: ok. i don't actually have a physical device (yet)...so i don't know how one views files there (i'm an iPad owner). so i guess i cannot help you. good luck!