# how to install .apk in a portable android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk

I followed the instruction on this tutorial [How do you install an APK file in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator) but it doesnt install the apk. instead, it gives me this message  "adb is not recognized as an internal or external command"

i think the problem here is im using a portable adt plugin and also a portable eclipse. is there anyway to install a downloaded apk file in my portable emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Yay! :) [See this](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-install-apk-files-android-windows-sdk-emulator)

Comment: How is this emulator portable?
Is it possible to run this emulator with installed .apk on another computer?

Answer (score 2):

go to your platform-tools folder from your android sdk dir and try in **cmd** promt

```
adb -e install c:/Projectapk_folder/yourapk.apk
```

**Note**: Emulator is in running mode.

**EDIT:** type adb command and check

```
C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
0A3AAD40xxxx2F        device
```

Comment: im sorry, i dont get it. do i need to type it on cmd?

Comment: yes you need to do it there only. make sure for windows is it adb.exe?

Comment: it still didnt work. cmd always says  "adb is not recognized as an internal or external command" :(

Answer (score 0):

Just try this solution....

Click emulator Setting Click Apps First uninstall your app and again install

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way ever 
1- First play the emulator from AVD manager
2- Just drag the .apk file and drop on the emulator screen
I tried on mac and it works well