# Unable to access Internet from Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, proxy

I'm unable to access the internet from android emulator. 
I tried

```
Menu --> Settings -->Wireless and Networks -->Mobile Networks -->Access Point Names -->TelKila Internet
```

then
`entered Proxy, Port, Username and Password also server address.`

in my android emulator.
But still I can't access the internet

I keep getting this error:

```
Error code 407: Proxy authentication required. The ISA Server requires authentication to fulfill the request. Access to the web proxy filter is denied. (12209) ...
```

Is there a way to setup proxy for android from code ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes friend. Me only asked the same question yesterday. But There is no answer friend. That is why asking new question. Please don't mistake me friend. I need solution. This is my big problem friend.

Comment: did you try it with other emulator?

Comment: Yes friend. I checked with 4 sample emulators with different versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a two step solution and I hope it works for you. I am afraid, I could come up with nothing simpler. :-(

But this *should* get you started.

**Step 1:**

Download an APK: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1359389. [Direct Link to the APK](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1491353&d=1353246617)

**Step 2:** *SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3480235/450534*

```
1. Execute the emulator.
2. Start the console (Windows XP), Run -> type **cmd**, and move to the **platform-tools** folder of **SDK** directory. 
3. Paste the *APK* file in the 'platform-tools' folder.
4. Rename the APK to `proxy.apk` or something simple that you will find easy to type in a Command Prompt. The name itself does not matter. The **.apk** extension does.
4. Then type the following command.
> adb install [apk file name]

 Example:
> adb install Jorgesys.apk
```

Now, you will installed the application linked in *Step 1* on your emulator. Configure the settings in the app and you should have Internet working on the emulator.

Let me know how it goes.

Note: The app is also available on Google Play and has a few screenshots that might help you get started: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid

*Disclosure: I have nothing to do with this app. I found it while searching for some solutions for the OP. Nothing more.*