# How to install openCV on android emulator

Tags: android, opencv, configuration, virtual

I have to install openCV on a emulator. Somebody wrote that is should use a certain command

`adn install <...>/OpenCV-2.4.3.2-android-sdk/apk/OpenCV_2.4.3.2_Manager_2.4_x86.apk`

but did not say where to put it? I did not see any command line do configure virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the OpenCV Manager on emulator is like installing any other application. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator) on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it on a VirtualBox appliance.

http://dimitri-christodoulou.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/how-to-install-opencv-on-android-vm.html