# Run apk on android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, apk

I want to run APK on android emulator and I followed next steps:

1. Copied apk to platform-tools directory
2. Run cmd.exe as administrator
3. Navigated to the platform-tools directory
4. Run emulator from AVD manager
5. In command line entered adb devices (it showed my emulator in list)
6. I entered adb insall name.apk in command line after this I got message as below:

[image]

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator) how to run APK on emulator. And other tutorial also show how it works. In case when we entered adb install after few seconds command line shows Success message but in my case command line shows this log.

Comment: At least tell us what command you issued! Are you trying to connect to a real device? If so, how's the device configured? Have you been able to run the apk on an emulator?

Comment: That actually isn't an error.  It's the usage for the adb command.  It usually means what you typed was syntactically incorrect.  We can't help you unless you tell us what you typed.

Comment: Got it. I changed description

Comment: Yep, the question was bad for understanding

Comment: I also found info about variables in system preferences, but it was just in one of many tutorials that I have read. (add the path of it to environment variable in variable PATH "you might need restart")

Comment: I'm guessing you actually typed "adb install name.apk" instead of "insall" like you have in the question

Comment: Also, your apk needs to be in the same directory as adb.exe if you do not have platform-tools added to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: it is horrible you are right. it is my mistake I entered insall. omg (facepalm)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you already have the Emulator running follow these steps:

- Locate your **adb.exe** file in your Android SDK folde.In Windows
  environment normally your **adb.exe** is inside
  **[Android-SDK-folder]/platform-tools/**. In my case, the **adb.exe** is in
  **C:\android-juno\android-sdk\platform-tools**.
- Put it inside your **[Android-SDK-folder]/platform-tools/** as bellow figure:

  [image]
- Now run the adb.exe through the command prompt.
- In the command line, go inside the platform-tools folder.Execute command:

  **adb install Peribahasa.apk**
  [image]

  Later, the apps you just install will be in the emulator.