# Eclipse running apk file that was imported

Tags: android, eclipse

I have imported apk file that was already been extracted exactly like this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12370973/3289129

Now the problem is to make this project that has imported to Eclipse be able to run in the android emulator without error?

Anyone has any suggestion or guidelines on what can I do next in the Eclipse environment? Linking with database and manifest? websites, links or videos? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Below 2 links may help you:

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371015/run-apk-on-android-emulator/17372662#17372662
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator

Comment: I need to know how it can run in the eclipse environment, do u have any ideas? About linking back all the database and manifast.

Answer (score 0):

Listen Some Applications Code are being Obfuscated.

So You Do one thing open the Java Decompiler and add all the .class Files.

And try to Gain the Logic Behind the Application by implementing it in a NEW ANDROID PROJECT.

Hope it may Help You !!!

Comment: I need to know how it can run in the eclipse environment, do u have any ideas? About linking back all the database and manifest.

Comment: Listen do one thing the files u will get after implementing apktool in cmd...

open the eclipse and drag the files u require to know its coding.
You can traverse all the code by this.
Reply back if need any help !!!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I retrieved all the codes, I wanted to have these codes to be run and successfully run in the android emulator when I compile it. I'm still new in this, can I ask you in hangout or google+ when I really need help in emergency?

Comment: Thanks its my pleasure to help someone.