# Ho an i install an APk file on AVD in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk, android-virtual-device

I have searched a lot many links on how to install an APk file on emulator ,But its really cumbersome and typical task i ever done.So can anyone please tell me any good reference or how to install an apk on AVD in android?

Comment: Is this what you were looking for ? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator); a step by step guide, posted on SO.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

open terminal or Cmd

go to sdk Platform-tool path

than type command

adb install test.apk