# Android studio - deploy the release apk instead of debug

Tags: android, android-studio

The run configurations in Android Studio only let you deploy the default (debugging) APK, but I have built a release APK by running gradle assembleDebug from within Android Studio (as an external tool) and would like to deploy that instead. But it doesn't seem like you can change the APK which Android Studio installs. There is an option to deploy a custom artifact, but I'm not sure what that is, or if it would help, and anyway, there doesn't seem to be an option to create a new artifact in the Android Studio Project Structure dialog.

Does anyone know how I can specify the path of the APK which Android Studio deploys? I know I can install from the command line with adb, but it would speed things up if I could just click a button. Thanks.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

On the left should be a "Build Variants" tab. There you can switch between your build types. If there no tabs visible than look left buttom for a monitor symbol and click it. Then you should find the build types. The selected one will be installed.

Comment: @nenick Sorry, I don't see that. Where is that BuildVariants Tab supposed to be?

Comment: when it is not visible, look for a small monitor symbol located left bottom corner oat Android studio. When you click it then the build variants tab should be visible on the left not far above the monitor symbol.

Comment: Just want to add (this confused me) that even if there is no [V] dropdown button, just click on the selected build type to get the menu! Great Answer!

Comment: on Android Studio 3 if you don't find Build Variants you can make it appear clicking on View->Tool Windows->BuildVariants

Answer (score 66):

Click the `Build Variation` tab on the far left side. If it is not there, press the monitor icon in the far left corner (the darker gray area):

[image: Monitor Icon]

In the build variation tab change from `debug` to `release` by clicking the list item.

[image: Build Variation]

Answer (score 12):

Run a command

```
./gradlew assemble<variant_name>
//for example
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

[[package aar]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61918303/4770877)

After success build you can find `.apk` file at

```
project_path/app/build/outputs/apk/<variant_name>/
//for example
project_path/app/build/outputs/apk/release/
```

or just install via adb

```
adb install apk_path
```

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#changing-variant)

Comment: this produces an `app-release-unsigned.apk` which can't be installed without adb, anyway to install a release without adb?

Answer (score 0):

Build Variants can be changed as mentioned in the below image:

[image]

But other than that I was facing one more issue. If we keep the Build Variant as **Release** in the tab and set the below property in **build.gradle** file.

> debuggable true

Our project will be considered debuggable even though the Build Variant is selected as Release. So, once the testing is done. We can set the debuggable as false or we can remove the property itself. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find 'Build Variants' tab anyway, here are two methods:

You can:

- Double press shift, search 'Build Variants'.

Or you can:

- Click 'More tool windows' (icon looks like three dots) on the left top of the IDE, then select 'Build Variants'[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz5z7.png)

[Image of location of 'Build Variants' in 'More tool windows'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz5z7.png)

Once you found the 'Build Variants' tab, you can switch between 'release' and 'debug' mode.