# How to create a release Android library package (AAR) in Android Studio (not debug)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I have built my Android library package ([AAR](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library)) and the result of build is created in the
"..\app\build\outputs\aar" folder.

The file within this folder is called "app-debug.aar", so I guess it has been built in debug mode, so I would like to know how to generate the release built, that is, "app-release.aar". How can I do this?

Also, is it possible to generate the build with another custom name, for example, "myCustomAppName-release.aar" instead of "app-release.aar"?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#buildRelease

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? I have the same issue and can not find any help with it.

Answer (score 124):

In Android Studio 1.2+, there is a context panel listing all available Gradle tasks.

I found this panel on the right side of the IDE with default options enabled.

[image: The Gradle menu is on the right side of the IDE by default...]

Right-click the task you want and click "Run".

[image: Right-click the task you want a click "RUN"]

Comment: This works for me, but I noticed that the build from the standard 'build' menu also started working once I had run the cmd line grade commands suggested by user1624552 in comments for another answer here. It would be useful if someone who has not run the command line grade can confirm this side gradle menu approach works also as I noticed the command line downloaded what looked like a new version of gradle in my case before it ran and I wonder if that also is a required step.

Comment: BTW, well done finding this!!! If anyone from Google is looking at this it would be nice to know if there are any plans to link/rationalise/explain the top Build menu, this 'new' Gradle side menu, and the Build Variants view etc?

Comment: Yeah, definitely. I too ran gradle from the commandline as the others answers had suggested until I found that menu. I am not sure that running it from the commandline is required first before using the side menu...

What is interesting too is that whatever task you run from the side gradle menu becomes the default action "Run" action. So, in other words, the green arrow icon and the Run menu point to the last run gradle task. Useful :)

Comment: just one question,when you export aar files in release mode,will it itncludes latest proguard properties with it ?

Comment: i want to export an aar file ,with having a code obfuscation which is provided by proguard ?

Comment: Yes, if you run the `assemble` task, it will apply whatever progaurd rules you have defined in your project.

Comment: This menu was not available for me for my library.

Comment: @K.R.SaravanaKumar are you sure that you have the proper `gradle` configuration file within your library?

Answer (score 21):

**Create .aar**

You can use the command line:

```
./gradlew <moduleName>:assemble

./gradlew <moduleName>:assemble<build_variant>

# For example
./gradlew <moduleName>:assembleRelease

# Or
./gradlew <moduleName>:bundle<build_variant>Aar

# For example
./gradlew <moduleName>:bundleReleaseAar
```

The output is located at:

```
<project_path>/build/outputs/aar/<module_name>-<build_variant>.aar
```

Alternatively, you can use the Android Studio UI:

Menu *View* → *Tool Windows* → *Gradle
<module_name>* → *Tasks* → *Build or others* → *assembleRelease*

Comment: what is the difference between `./gradlew <moduleName>:assemble<build_variant>` and 
`./gradlew <moduleName>:bundle<build_variant>Aar` ?

Answer (score 17):

This issue can already be handled with the answers like execute

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

or choose `assembleRelease` from Android Studio's Gradle menu.

**However, for completeness**, with Android Studio 1.5.1 (and probably also older versions) building release version of a .aar can be accomplished by selecting **Build->Build APK** in **Android Studio**. It seems to execute assembleRelease. If your project only contains the library project, it does not ask for any signing information.

Comment: Issue of what?...

Answer (score 14):

I faced this issue in Android Studio 2.3.3 and solved it by changing the build variant of the module to release and building it again:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

With Android Studio 3.0, it is easier to generate an AAR file. From the Gradle option, check for the option as shown in the picture:

[image]

Comment: In my project i am not able to see assemble release option.

Comment: when i import my release .aar lib in a project  it rise an error like "AAPT: error: attribute ... not found" @leeCoder

Answer (score 13):

From Android Studio v4.x:

1. Select the *Build Variant* tab
2. Choose release mode
3. Then menu *Build* → *Make module...*
4. Click build from the top menu → *Rebuild project*

Your .aar file will be found in the project file hierarchy on the left, under `MyLibrary/Build/outputs` (you may need to first change the view from **Android view** to **Project view**, to see these files - using the dropdown at the top left corner).

[image: Build AAR library release]

Comment: This is the modern answer that worked for me

Answer (score 7):

1. Add the following script to your *android{}* tag in file *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* to generate a release build:

   ```
    signingConfigs {
        testConfig{
            storeFile file("X:/XXXX/yourkeystore")
            storePassword "yourKeyPassword"
            keyAlias "yourAlias"
            keyPassword "yourAliasPassword"
        }
    }

    buildTypes{
        release {
            signingConfig  signingConfigs.testConfig
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
   ```
2. Run command "gradle clean build" in your command line.

Comment: Sorry, I am newbie in Android development. Is it 
strictly necessary to sign an android library package (aar) to get its release output? How can I generate my own key store?

Comment: In my library project, \build\outputs\aar is already generate: XX-debug.aar, XX-release.aar. And Why you nedd a .arr file? If you want to use a library, just add following script in you build.gradle: dependencies {
    compile project(':YourLibraryProject')
}

Comment: I want to use this library within my android apps in future. This is a library and I want to obtain its release output but I do not understand why but I am obtaining only XX-debug.aar and not XX-release.aar in my library's "\app\build\outputs\aar" folder.

Comment: Sorry to tell you: Gradle build does not support local aar dependencies, you can visit: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55863

Comment: From a terminal windows, once in project folder, I have executed the following commands: "./gradlew clean" and "./gradlew aR" and now "XX-release.aar" is generated into "..\app\build\outputs\aar" folder. How can I do the same from Android Studio? that is, to tell Android Studio to assemble the Release as well.

Comment: Also how can I force a custom name instead of the preceding "app" in the  "app-debug.aar" and "app-release.aar" files? I would like to be able to change "app" prefix by a desired one, that is fore example, "myCustomName-debug.aar" and "myCustomName-release.aar"

Comment: Bill, this is not totaly true that Gradle does not support local aar dependencies, please, read at the end of your posted URL. There is a workaround to do it. Also described here: http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2014/05/18/reference-a-local-aar-in-your-android-project

Comment: To set custom name for aar output file I have finally done this (instead of using applicationVariants use libraryVariants instead): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114073/could-not-find-property-outputfile-on-com-android-build-gradle-internal-api-ap

Comment: Did you solve on generating the release.aar file? I have the same problem and cannot solve it...

Comment: Normally all you need to do is build the project in android studio but I have this same issue in a couple of apps. So doing it in the terminal is the only solution.

Answer (score 7):

**Part 1**: How can we create a release-only `*release.aar`?

Run in Android Studio `terminal` (or any terminal in your project folder):

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

You don’t need signing the configuration for such task.

**Part 2**: How can we rename the output library to `AnotherLibraryName-release.aar`?

Add to your module `gradle.build`:

```
android{
    project.archivesBaseName = "AnotherLibraryName"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set up your project as an Android library. 
In the *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* file:  `plugin: 'com.android.library'` 
You can see the output in: `build/outputs/aar/[your module]` 
Also see *[AAR Format](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format)*.

Answer (score 0):

For me, simply fixing a layout bug in the library that did not produce compile error (missing [Android X](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) plugin) fixed it and `<lib>-release.aar` appeared alongside the `<lib>-debug.aar` in the `build/outputs/aar/` folder.