# Android Studio library not building release aar, only debug

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, release

I have a project in Android Studio with three libraries in it.
I'm building a set of common libraries used in a number of other projects.
Everything works great, except the build process.

I have three library modules: `tools`, `database`, and `core`.

If I set the build variant to debug, I get in the build/outputs/aar folder the proper files:

```
tools-debug.aar
database-debug.aar
core-debug.aar
```

When I set the build variant to release, however, I only get

```
tools-release.aar
database-release.aar
```

There is no `core-release.aar`.

The only way to generate it is to open the Gradle slider on the right hand side, and manually run assembleRelease.

I've compared all the gradle files and all other files I can find and they are all identical between the three libraries.  Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: This seems to be a common problem.  Also asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167898/why-wont-android-studio-create-my-aar-file-in-release-mode and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646262/how-to-create-a-release-android-library-package-aar-in-android-studio-not-deb.