# How to create a jar file from android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

> How to create jar file from android project which contains facebook library and viewPager library in android studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309950/create-aar-file-in-android-studio
Check this one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646262/how-to-create-a-release-android-library-package-aar-in-android-studio-not-deb

Answer (score 2):

> Its working for me
>
> 1. Enter your java source file
> 2. alter your manifest file like as below

```
Manifest File:

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'  
android 
{      
compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig 
   {

        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile project(':facebook')
}
task deleteOldJar(type:Delete){
    delete 'release/FacebookSharingApi.jar'
}
task exportJar(type:Copy){
from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('release/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar','FacebookSharingApi.jar')
}
exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar,build)
```

> 3. Click the expostJar(Task) --- Follow below steps

```
    > Right side of your android studio 
    > --- Gradle 
       --- Gradle project 
         ---   click refresh button 
            --- app ---others -- (ExportJar)
```