# Android studio, how to convert android application to aar library?

Tags: android

I'm new in android programming, I need to convert android app to be AAR library, and be informed the android app has activities and I want to use them. 
Can you help me step by step.

Note: 
I have read about create new module and choose library, but I don't know how to complete this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a release android library package (aar) in Android Studio (not debug)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646262/how-to-create-a-release-android-library-package-aar-in-android-studio-not-deb)

Comment: I need the method to convert the existing android app to be AAR library, and then I can use this library with its activities,
I know how to create AAR library.

Comment: Simply, You cant convert an application code with Activities to a library (.jar/.aar)

Comment: Thanks, @RevanthKrishnaKumarV.
but can I divide my app to (included libraries + java source code) to be aar library, and when I'm included this library build the activeties?
Actually, I have tried to replace in build gridle (apply plugin: 'com.android.application') to (apply plugin: 'com.android.library'), and delete the applicationId,  I have an aar library but when I have included to other android app, I have many errors like (Error:(42, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'enabled' with value '@bool/use_activity').)