# How to create new Android AAR in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, aar

I am trying to create an Andoid AAR library to contain commonly used utility functions. I followed the instructions in https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library
exactly. Namely:
1. File->New->New Module
2. Click "Android Library" then Next
3. Tried to use defaults: "My Library", "mylibrary" and SDK Version, but Finish button is grayed out and error message appeared: "The module location is inside Studio's install location."
I see no place to enter a module's location. I've tried variations on Libray name and Module name with no joy.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The link you provided is about creating projects as libraries modules for your main app, to generate an aar you should look something else

Comment: "to generate an aar you should look something else"? Hardly a useful suggestion. If you have a concrete positive suggestion, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of unsuccessful head-banging with the IDE, I found an astoundingly simple solution in some Google results, namely:

1. Manually edit  *project*/app/build.gradle
2. Change **apply plugin: 'com.android.application'** to **apply plugin: 'com.android.library'**
3. Remove the line specifying **applicationId**.
4. Build->Clean Project and Build->Rebuild Project.

Voila! New library **app-debug.aar** appears in *project*/app/build/outputs/aar/
I don't know where the name app-debug came from, but you can rename it afterwards if you like.

UPDATE 7/2/18

I omitted precursor steps to this procedure. They are
1. Create a base project however you normally do.
2. Delete classes and other stuff you don't need in the aar.
3. Follow the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

you are able to use command line tool to create `.aar` file

```
./gradlew <moduleName>:assemble
```

[[Example here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61918303/4770877)