# How to create a standalone android aar library project?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want to create a project that simply creates an aar library.  Everything I see on google is about doing that from an 'existing project' which I do not want.  That seems to tie into just that project.  When I click new project in android studio, I don't see an option for 'library' and it creates an application every time :(.

How does one simply create a project that creates an aar artifact?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a workaround since the answer to my question is NO :(.  Wow!!  Why in the world can you not create a library?

Anyways, the answer on this one is what I do now as it seems the cleanest

[How to create new Android AAR in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51107185/how-to-create-new-android-aar-in-android-studio)