# How to build AAR from Android Library?

Tags: android

I've followed [the official guide on creating Android libraries](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library), but something doesn't quite seem to be working for me.

My project consists of two modules. One app module titled "app" and one library module titled "bfsdk". In my app's `build.gradle` file I include the library like so:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(path: ':bfsdk')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Then in my library module my `build.gradle` specifies that it's a library in the first line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

According to the documentation I should now just:

> select the library module in the **Project** window and then click **Build > Build APK**

And this should build the AAR file. However:

[image]

[image]

When I click on this and wait for the whole build process to complete, I can't find an AAR file anywhere. This generates an APK file in `~/Source/BluePlayer/app/build/outputs/apk/android/release` but there is no `build` directory in the `~/Source/BluePlayer/bfsdk` folder.

What am I doing wrong? What step am I missing? Where is the AAR file supposed to appear?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Referencing [Create aar file in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309950/create-aar-file-in-android-studio), try to simply `Build > Rebuild project`. AAR file should appear in `~/Source/BluePlayer/bfsdk/build/outputs/aar`

Comment: Using `Rebuild Project` (per the SO post) rather than `Build APK` (per the Google documentation) worked

Answer (score 1):

Command line command will be executed under the hood

for example

```
./gradlew <moduleName>:assembleRelease
```

[[Read more here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61918303/4770877)