# Is it possible to Install Android Package (.apk) on the emulator without access to sources?

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, android-emulator

I think the answer is No but I’m not 100% sure as I’m a newbie with Android SDK.

So, I downloaded adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702 to my CentOS 6.5 machine. Following the documentation, I was able to create an AVD using ‘AVD Manager’ interface (using the `eclipse` binary).

I’m able to view my AVD that I created by running `emulator -avd <name>`. 
 I have a .apk file which I didn’t build but downloaded from a website (I don’t have the source code). If I would like to load this .apk into my emulator to see how it works, is it something that’s doable? If yes, may I know the steps please?

Many thanks in advance.

Update:

Following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator), I tried:

> adb install /path/to/my.apk

which returns,

> “failed to copy ‘/path/to/my.apk’ to ‘/data/local/tmp/my.apk’: No such file or directory”

I also tried copying /path/to/my.apk to the directory where adb is located. I created a /data/local/tmp directory as well with the same result. Perhaps, it’s looking for /data/local/tmp on the AVD (?). Not even sure if it is a compatible issue with the device/target/cpu configured on my AVD ..

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to install an APK to a compatible, fully functional emulator.  But your error message makes it seem like your emulator is broken - a not uncommon problem.  Are you authorized to install this on an emulator?  Is it huge?

Comment: why not just install it via the emulator, in other words, copy it over, then use the emulator, navigate to the apk directory and tap to install.

Comment: Not a bad idea - probably necessary to either add an SD card image, put it on a web server with the proper MIME type, or email it to an account on the device.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes, an SD card image sounds like a great idea or even somewhere on a webserver where you can download it from.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, It's a public website so I believe I'm authorized. File size is about 7.4 MB. I don't know if it is 'huge'.

Comment: @Janpan, Thanks! I'm able to view my instance running (finally!). I used `./emulator -avd test0` as you suggested. When you say, 'navigate to the apk directory', are you refering to 'navigate on the device'? If yes, how? @ChrisStratton, I see my 'SD Card' is empty (navigated from 'MENU button -> Manage Apps -> SD Card'). Looks like I should be able to install from here if I can copy the .apk to this location? Many thanks to you both for the help here.

Comment: I see I have an SD card image (sdcard.img) under ~/.android/avd/test0.avd/. Documentation says I should be able to copy using `adb push <local> <remote>`. I guess I have to mount sdcard.img as the <remote>?

Comment: Looks like `adb push <my.apk> /sdcard/` worked. I can confirm that the file is copied on `adb shell` followed by `ls /sdcard/<my.apk>`.  Many thanks for the help!