# Running 3rd party android/ios app automatically

Tags: android, ios, frameworks, emulation, automated-tests

I have the following question to ask the wisdom of SO community:

What I have:
A bunch of 3rd party .apk/.ipa file which I don't have source code of.

What I'm trying to do:
Automatically run apps in emulator or other testing frameworks to generate/record app's network traffic. (I'm aware of the fact that lots of apps require login/signup in the first page, some sort of human involvement is okay)

All I care is the running network traffic from individual apps. The traffic sniffing part is straightforward. Any suggestion of open source or commercial emulator/testing frameworks available to archive what I'm trying to do?

Thanks very much.

Edit: seems the "Monkey" tool is promising for Android platform. Any similar tool available for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Dont know what you mean by 'automatically', but for Android my first try would be Android Virtual Device AVD Emulator, shipped with Android Studio or ADT Bundle for Eclipse.

Then install .apk files [this way.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator)

Comment: By 'automatically', I mean I can start/stop running a app with some sort of script, and the testing framework/emulator can pork around the app with as little human intervention as possible (click all buttons etc.) to generate some network traffic.

Comment: On Android, ADB (also part of the SDK) will do what you need from a command line.  It can start apps and kill their processes - a little more involved since you need shell commands but easily Googled.

Comment: And as emulator supports keyboard input, you could script keyboard input events.