# Android app dosen't run on device

Tags: java, android

The app I'm currently developing works perfectly on the simulator.

When plugging in my Android device and press "run", nothing happens on the device.

We have done a lot of code and don’t want to restart everything, we can run different project but not this one. Why ?

On the Emulator it works fine and we got no problems.

The app gets installed on the phone if we look in Settings->program handler but I can’t find it in all programs.

Comment: Have you tried [installing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3480235/1960180) the program and [running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools) it using ADB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forgot: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" in AndroidManifest, this property add your app (Icon) in list of app.

```
<activity android:name="com.test.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```