# How to install an apk in one of the connected devices through adb?

Tags: android, command-line, adb

I have multiple devices/emulators connected to my computer and I want to install an apk or run other adb commands in one of the devices.

How do I do that?

Comment: if you know, why did you ask this question anyway ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you install an APK file in the Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator)

Comment: Are you not aware of http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to install apk

1. Multiple Emulator and one device attached you want to install apk on device :

   adb -d install `<path of apk>`
2. Multiple Emulator and Multiple device attached And you want to install on device :

A. Get devices name and serial numbver.

```
adb devices
```

B. Now install apk on given device id.

adb -s `<serial number of device>` install `<path of apk>`

3. Multiple Emulator And you want to install on selected emulater:

   adb -e install `<path of apk>`

For more detail please follow below link: 
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
adb devices
```

to get list of all connected devices. Then use

```
adb -s <deviceId> install abc.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

You may query the list of devices connected to your computer with:

```
adb devices
```

Then you may run any `adb` command for one of the devices like:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 install myAPK.apk
```