# how to deploy cordova app to android without auto-launching app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, deployment

Using the CLI is there any method to deploy/install an app to an android (or ios) device without the app auto launching?  I need to test a scenario where a user deploys an app to the phone (say, via app store) but doesn't `launch/open` the app from the store (they just close store and go back to device....and first-run app another time)

Something like: `cordova run android --target=x1233455 --no-run`

I have tried:

```
cordova build android --device=x1233455
cordova build android --target=x1233455
```

I found a method via Xcode for iOS but haven't been able to find something for native cordova (or Ionic).  It worked perfect for my testing.  If a method is not available for cordova cli (for android), then is there a method to do this in Android Studio?

Comment: Look at the `adb` command, [How to install an apk in one of the connected devices through adb?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29339275/295004)

Comment: heh, that simple.  `adb install app.apk` - installs without running - well, so I have read.  I never really used `adb` for other than managing connected devices - always used `ionic/corodva run/build` commands.  Going to be testing here shortly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that might need the solution to this (credit to: @MorrisonChang ):

`adb -s <DEVICE ID> install <PATH TO APK>`