# After updating android studio Uploading apk stuck on emulator

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

[image]

I have created new android project and then trying to install my build on emulator. Gradle Build works fine but when it tries to upload apk it get stuck

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator?rq=1 Did you follow this?

Comment: @Zimano i know this way to upload the apk but i don't know why it not uploading now. It was working fine when i was using android studio version 1.5.0 and when i have updated my android studio version 1.5.1 it is not working

Comment: @Naveed Did you download the latest system images from the SDK manager ? Did you try to recreate your Virtual Device?

Comment: Yes @Hemix i have updated all system images. Yes now there is no update available in sdk manager. Also i have updated the haxm.

Comment: Now restarted the system somehow it is working now. Thanx