# Error: Could not automatically detect an ADB binary. Some emulator functionality will not work until a custom path to ADB is added in the extended…

Tags: android, adb

I'm getting an error message in Android Studio with adb:

> Could not automatically detect an ADB binary. Some emulator functionality will not work until a custom path to ADB is added in the extended settings page.

[Screenshot showing the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtxVc.png)

Note that I have adb as part of the development tools and have set variable path, have tested in cmd and it's functional.

What am I missing here?
Do I have to set some path to adb in Android Studio as well?

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

that error happens because your anti-virus moved the adb.exe to the vault and block it, so you need to give that file an exception that it is not a virus, if that didn't fix it you may need to uninstall the SDK tools and reinstall it again to work.

open the SDK manager in the Android Studio (a button somewhere in the top menu, android logo with a down arrow), switch to the SDK tools tab and select/install the Android SDK Platform-tools.

Alternatively, you can try the standalone SDK Manager: Open the SDK manager and you should see a "Launch Standalone SDK manager" link somewhere at the bottom of the settings window. Click and open the standalone SDK manager, then install/update the

"Tools > Android SDK platform tools".

If the above does not solve the problem, try reinstalling the tools: open the "Standalone SDK manager" and uninstall the Android SDK platform-tools, delete the [your SDK directory]/platform-tools directory completely and install it again using the SDK manager.

Answer (score 12):

In my case Macbook M1, I just tried following steps:

- Android Studio: Menu -> Tools -> **SDK Manager** select **SDK Tools** Tab and **Uncheck** -> **Android SDK Platform-Tools**
- Close Android Studio, close simulator
- Start Android Studio and Now **Select/Check** -> **Android SDK Platform-Tools**
- Open Simulator and build the Application ( Working fine )

Answer (score 6):

This is mostly because of Windows antivirus. To solve it follow these steps:

Click the Start button.

Type “Windows Security”.

Click on “Virus and threat protection”.

Click on “Manage settings” under “Virus & threat protection settings”.

Scroll down if needed, and then click on “Add or remove exclusions”.

[image]

[image]

Press the + button, choose "process" and add each of these processes.

1.Gradle cache :
%USERPROFILE%.gradle

2.Android Studio projects :
%USERPROFILE%\AndroidStudioProjects

3.Android SDK :
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\SDK

For example this is how you add the first one.Just choose "Process" and copy and paste this and then "Add".

[image]

After adding all three of them to the exclusion, just run your app again and it will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

i also got this error, re-installing the sdk-platform-tools isn't a quick solution,...finally fix it by switching off the emulator manually then switching it back on from android studio avd manager

[image: Adb Error fix]

Comment: This helped me :) (long press)

Answer (score 1):

Open Android Studio
Go to: Menu -> Tools -> SDK Manager
Click on SDK Tools Tab,
Now Check on - "Android SDK Platform-Tools"
Click on OK to install.
Now you should see "Virtual Device" under Device Connector (just next to build icon)
Run your App and it should start in Native M1 Android Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

thank you @FARAZ, worked for me on my M1 as well!

i'm using VSCode and after unselected/selecting the `Android SDK Platform-Tools` I was able to go into the Emulator on VSCode and it prompted me to install some Xcode stuff on the android emulator and then it worked!

Comment: How is this answer different from the other answers?

Comment: lol sorry, I don't have 50 points so I can't write comments on other people's posts. so i wrote a new answer lol xD

Answer (score 0):

for me go to the avd manager and do cold boot and run the app. it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

On my MacBook Pro M1 I had to either install a new emulator or wipe data/cold boot every time. I’m sure there’s a better solution but this is a quick fix