# Disable notification that Android Studio is unable to automatically detect ADB binary

Tags: java, android

I run my virtual device in Android Studio and I get this message.

"Could not automatically detect an ADB binary. Some emulator functionality will not work until a custom path to ADB is added. This can be done in Extended Controls (...) > Settings > General tab > 'Use Detected ADB location'".

I really want to stop this from appearing so someone please help.

Comment: this might help
https://stackoverflow.com/q/46290668/2930834

Comment: @Nisa Efendioglu, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Have you tried turning off notifications?