# Visual studio code can't detect emulator device or phone connected

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

I was running my app with vscode using Android emulator or my phone, however all of a sudden vscode could not identify any device or emulator that I connect (no devices). phone is in debug mode or even the android emulator. Also When I try starting the emulator I get this warning
[image]

Comment: Does `adb devices -l` list the device?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like `adb` can't be found. Have you updated or moved the (Android) SDK recently?

You may want to check your platform-tools folder in your Android SDK and if necessary, download the tools again (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48219297/25124)).

Answer (score 14):

When using an actual device with VSCode/Android Studio, you must switch on both:

1. Developer Mode
2. USB Debugging Mode

Comment: I sometimes have to turn Debugging Mode off and then on again, not really sure why, but it asks me to trust the PC and I press `allow`, then it pops up, thank you! Also: unlocking the phone may be necessary

Answer (score 2):

Happened me sometimes. problem was avast antivirus software it puts that adb file to virus chest

Comment: So, what you do to fix this problem. Disable Antivirus app? I'm Disabled it but not the same problem

Comment: Nope I checked virus chest of avast and found adb.exe file there and I restored it. Then it worked normal

Answer (score 2):

There are various reason of happening this but one common solution to this problem is go and open platform-tools folder and check for adb.exe if it exists there copy the link from above address bar and put it into environment variable path that's it.
By default platform-tools folder comes with sdk installtation but in case if you don't have one then you can download it from below link https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools
[open this image to see the path variable][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dttn0.png

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in vscode, i have already Enabled Developer Option,
USB Debugging,

But still hasn't Device detected in vs code,

And Then i have Added , Android SDK , Platforms And Platform-tools folder paths into Environmental Variable , Then vscode detected my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, until I turned on "enable usb debbuging" After my Android phone was connected to the laptop using usb cable and got the RSA key popup. If you never got that popup. Try to connect your phone to the laptop first and then turn on the "enable usb debbuging".