# Flutter app is not opening in android emulator

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

App is not opening in android emulator, while I run through "flutter run", the app is launching and opens in the emulator and works fine. But while using VS code "Start Debugging" or "Run Without Debugging" then app is not opening in emulator. Getting the billow lines in debug console.

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode... main.dart:1

✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.

Exited

1. Wipe Data (delete datas from emulator)
2. "Cold boot now"

Comment: i think android sdk is not set up properly, 
run command  in terminal [flutter doctor -v] and find issues 
if this is not an issue then  check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194183/visual-studio-code-cant-detect-emulator-device-or-phone-connected/65367275#65367275