# Error "System UI isn't responding" while running AOSP build on emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-source

I am trying to run AOSP(oreo 8.1) build on emulator.

I used following commands to build AOSP.

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_arm-eng
make -j4
```

my build was successful. Now i'm trying to run on emulator using following command.

```
emulator
```

emulator is started with following warning message.

**Could not automatically detect an ADB binary. Some emulator functionality will not work until a custom path to ADB  is added in the extended settings page.**

After successful boot "**System UI isn't responding**" message is displaying on the emulator, also emulator is running real slow.

Any help in resolving this issue is greatly appreciated.

[emulator screenshot: system ui isn't responding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5Qpd.png)

```
emulator: WARNING: system partition size adjusted to match image file (2050 MB > 200 MB)
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
main-loop: WARNING: I/O thread spun for 1000 iterations
```

Answer (score 8):

It often occurs - especially on slow machines running CPU-consuming emulations, that an emulator would initially load into a state where a `System UI isn't responding` alert shows. It does not necessarily mean the device isn't working; Often enough, the alert can be dismissed and the device will be completely functional from that point on.

**I'm not sure what the exact issue to solve here is.** Nevertheless, assuming you're running on CI and - besides the emulator's sluggishness, wish to overcome the `System UI isn't responding` alert appearing upon boot completion (as suggested by the title) -- may I suggest [this bash script (gist)](https://gist.github.com/d4vidi/7862d60375b38f8970f824c4ce0ad2a9):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo ""
echo "[Waiting for launcher to start]"
LAUNCHER_READY=
while [[ -z ${LAUNCHER_READY} ]]; do
    UI_FOCUS=`adb shell dumpsys window windows 2>/dev/null | grep -i mCurrentFocus`
    echo "(DEBUG) Current focus: ${UI_FOCUS}"

    case $UI_FOCUS in
    *"Launcher"*)
        LAUNCHER_READY=true
    ;;
    "")
        echo "Waiting for window service..."
        sleep 3
    ;;
    *"Not Responding"*)
        echo "Detected an ANR! Dismissing..."
        adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN
        adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN
        adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Waiting for launcher..."
        sleep 3
    ;;
    esac
done

echo "Launcher is ready :-)"
```

The script awaits for the launcher to become ready and in-focus, and automatically dismisses system responsiveness alerts, coming its way.

It in no way addresses the emulator's sluggishness, however.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43064441/5132744) from another question to fix the ADB error. However, this will likely not fix the responsiveness of your emulator.

The emulator tends to function extremely slowly if you are compiling aosp for a different architecture than your host machine. If you are building on an x86 machine an x86 build will result in a significantly faster emulator that won't eat up all of your machine's resources.

Answer (score 0):

May be this answer could be helpful for someone who have made a mistake like me and could save his time.

I faced this issue on my physical device as i used an app icon of very large size (2100x2100). I resolved it by using an app icon of low size(512x512).